# Is it safe to reuse private variable names?

Tags: oop

So if I had 2 private classes, each containing a private variable named cost

would this work fine or should I use different variable names?

Comment: It is safe, but perhaps not clear to others reading your code and perhaps not mnemonic for you when you return after a long period away. But private variables are limited by scope to the class where they are defined, and if both named `foo` they will have different object ids in the overall object space.

Answer (score 1):

That will work fine. Private variables are only accessible from within the class, so there's no scope for ambiguity.

Comment: Private variables in a private class are accessible from the enclosing class as well.

Comment: Perhaps that varies from language to language? It's certainly not the case in C++.  It *is* true the other way around (a nested class can access private members of its enclosing class), but that's still within the initial class.